# Swagger YAML file add dynamic URL

Tags: swagger

How do I add a URL link to my swagger API, referencing localhost?.  I dont want to add a hardcoded URL to the file, as the URL will differ on each enviornment. Trying the method below (specifying localhost) does not work.

```
externalDocs:
  description: "View application metrics"
  url: "http://localhost:3001/metrics"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative externalDocs URLs are supported in OpenAPI 3.0 (`openapi: 3.0.0`) but not in OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`).

Assuming you use OpenAPI 3.0 and your OpenAPI file is hosted at http://localhost:3001/openapi.yaml, you can use:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

externalDocs:
  description: View application metrics
  url: /metrics     # <--- http://localhost:3001/metrics
```

**Note:** If your API definition includes `servers`, relative URLs are resolved against `servers` rather than the location of the OpenAPI file.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
...

servers:
  - url: 'https://api.example.com/v1'

externalDocs:
  description: View application metrics
  url: /metrics    # <--- https://api.example.com/metrics
```

More info: [API Host and Base Path](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/#relative)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below steps:

1. Convert the yaml in json
2. Change the host and save it
3. Convert the saved json again to yaml

In swagger it takes json file for documentation so you might don't require the 3rd step.

```
const path = require("path");
const yaml = require("js-yaml");
const fs = require("fs");

const host = "127.0.0.1:3000"; // any host
const doc = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync("swagger.yaml"));
doc.host = host;
fs.writeFileSync(
  path.join("swagger_new.json"),
  JSON.stringify(doc, null, "  ")
);
```

hope it helped!